# Forcing UISearchController to present search results table Fullscreen

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I have a UIViewController, that has Segmented Control and  UITableView in it.
All use Autolayout, set in the Storyboard. Here's the code version of constraints i set there:

```
H:|-[SegmentedControls]-| 
H:|[TableView]|
V:|-[SegmentedControls]-[TableView]|
```

I have added UISearchController and UISearchbar as a header view of the table.
For displaying search results, i create a new UITableViewController.

```
UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
self.clientListTable.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"Active", @"Inactive"];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

But then i came across a following issue - when i press on the search bar, it animates, but the presented view takes only a part of the screen, presented with dimmed chrome on top and bottom, instead of being presented fullscreen. 
Size of the presented view seems to be equal to one of the tableview, which hosts the search bar, just centred vertically on the screen.
I'm clueless on how to override the presentation of the search results, to make them take full screen. I tried to explicitly set **ModalPresentationStyle** on both presenting view controller and one being presented, but it didn't work. 
I'm getting a feeling that i would need to somehow override the presentation controller of the search results, but i don't know where to start, any ideas?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Apple's UICatalog sample code? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: That was one of first things i did, next one was asking on apple dev forums and apple dev support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a year of using workaround (manually managing input from UISearchBar, without UISearchController), i found a solution. SearchController presents a table with results in a new table, that is set to the same size as the table it was called from. So since my table was only part of the view, the presented table was also not full screen. 
Mistake i had, is that i did try to hide Segmented Controls, but i didn't update the constraints (still wasn't very good with auto layout back then). So after watching this year's WWDC presentation on "Mysteries of auto layout" i came up with a solution:

```
    -(void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:@[_constraintToTheSegmentalControls,_constraintToTheTop]];
                     [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[_constraintToTheTop]];
                     self.segmentedControls.hidden = YES;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
}

   -(void)didDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:@[_constraintToTheSegmentalControls,_constraintToTheTop]];
                     [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[_constraintToTheSegmentalControls]];
                     self.segmentedControls.hidden = NO;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
}
```

Constraint "constraintToTheSegmentalControls" is constraint from the top of the table view to the bottom of the segmented controls, by default is active.
Constraint "constraintToTheTop" is constraint from the top of the table view to the top layout guide, by default is inactive.
I added both of them as IB references to my view controller.

Animation still needs some tweaking but the solution is working.